# How to separate a string into substrings of two characters

Tags: java, string

I am trying to split strings in substrings of two chararters for example for the input: "ABCDE" i want to get the substrings "AB" "BC" "CD" "DE".

I tried with this:

```
String route = "ABCDE";
int i = 0;

 while(i < route.length()) {
            String sub = route.substring(i,i+2);
            System.out.println(sub);
            i++;
        }
```

but the index (i) gets out of range int the last iteration and causes an error.
is there any way to do this without getting the index (i) out of range  ?

Comment: Take a closer look at your i+2 and run through the code by hand, with the String "ABCDE". Does anything weird happen when you approach the end of your string?

Comment: Your need to iterate untill the length-1.I mean untill the i less than i<length-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine

```
String route = "ABCDE";
if( route.length() > 2){
    int i = 0;
    do {
        String res = route.substring(i,i+2);
        System.out.println(res);
        i++;
    } while (i + 1 < route.length());
}
else{
    System.out.println(route);
}
```

**Edit**: Added boundary case for the string has length less than 2

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the loop condition.

```
while(i < route.length()-1)
```

In your code i goes till (length-1) and than in the substring(i,i+2) function you gives end index i+2. It is higher than largest index of string.

Also, As far as I know calling a library function in a loop condition is not considered a good practice.

- In each iteration you call this function which is time consuming.
- control goes to that subroutine in each iteration.

A good alternative to this would be to store the length in a variable and use that in a condition.

```
int temp = route.length()-1;
while(i<temp){
```

Answer (score 0):

Add check for the size of the string to trap the error:

```
String route = "ABCDE";
int i = 0;

while(i < route.length()) {
  if(i < route.length() - 1) {
  String sub = route.substring(i,i+2);
  System.out.println(sub);
  } else {
    String sub = route.substring(i,i+1);
    System.out.println(sub);
  i++;
}
```

So whenever the i counter almost close to string size, get the last char.

Answer (score 0):

As denis already pointed out, the bug in the code is in the loop condition.

Should be: `while(i < route.length() - 1)`
. However, how about simplifying this logic to use a `for` loop.

```
String route = "ABCDE";
for (int i=0; i+2<=route.length(); i++)
  System.out.println(route.substring(i,i+2));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I forgot that java `endIndex` is exclusive. Updated to use `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an [`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) because you are trying to access an index of the `String` that doesn't exist.

To fix this, change your loop condition from

```
while(i < route.length())
```

to

```
while(i < route.length() - 1)
```

Without the `-1` on the last iteration of the `while` loop `i + 2` is equal to `7`<sup>1</sup> which is out of the `String`s bounds.

Another (cleaner) solution to this problem is a [`for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < route.length() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(route.substring(j, j + 2));
}
```

The `for` loop in this situation is just shorter as the declaration, conditional, and increment statements are all in one line.

<sup>1: This `7` reduces to `6` since the `endIndex` of `substring` is exclusive.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

you can not use 
`i < route.length()`,because when `i = 5`, `String sub = route.substring(i,i+2);` the `i+2=7`,is **out of index**,so use `i<route.length` instead

Comment: thank you, I'm a newer in stackoverflow~Now I konw how to add code